# Serializing DAG into DB on Demand in Airflow 2.0

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

We are currently deploying flows on runtime using Airflow and face constant issues in terms of DAG deployment . The DAGs doesnt get picked by Scheduler on time and delays the user response in our workflow application .

> Is their any way we can deploy DAGs into database of airflow ON DEMAND

? If not how can we make this process well defined .

Comment: What error do you see in the DAG Parsing Processor logs? You could see them at `$AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler/EXECUTION_DATE/DAG_ID.py.log`

Comment: We dont see any error , but the dag parsing itself takes more than 30 seconds and delays user response on application . We have tried reducing the scheduler time to pick up dags for parsing , but it did not help much .

Comment: In that case, change `[scheduler] min_file_process_interval` from `30` to `2` or so

Answer (score 0):

Each DAG file is parsed every 30 seconds by default from Airflow 2.0.1.

This is controlled by https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval

Change that to 2 seconds or whatever number of seconds you think is appropriate for your case.

Comment: We have already tried this approach but scheduler also needs some time to scan existing dags which are deployed . So the load is increasing on scheduler and we see dag parsing fails .

Comment: That means you might have tons of logic outside of DAG and Task object, please post logs and your DAG

Comment: Yes we are using PythonOperator which internally calls a method written in python class files. We can have operators in the dag ranging from 1 to somewhere 20 . The python class the code of respective ML operation the user intend to do , for eg imputations , classification , regression etc .

Comment: What can be done in terms of optimising DAG and associated dependencies ?